# Sending Emails With smtplib In Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am trying to send emails with Gmail through the SMTPlib, it works fine when I send them to myself, but every time I try to send an email to someone else it still sends it to my own email.

```
import smtplib as s

username = raw_input("Gmail Username: ")
password = raw_input("Gmail Password: ")
obj = s.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
obj.starttls()
obj.login(username, password)
v_email = raw_input("Email: ")
email_message = raw_input("Message: ")
obj.sendmail(username, v_email, email_message)
```

Comment: What do the email headers look like on the email that's sent?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see you adding the sender or any other headers to the e-mail. Which means the user is expected to type them as part of a message.

Comment: I am supposed to add From: and To: etc in it?
Sorry I am new to this

Comment: yea, you have to call `.mail(sender)` and `.rcpt(recipient)` first. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) has a nice example how smtp works.

Comment: Would anyone mind fixing my code? I am having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look a the example http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html, 
check how 'msg' is populated before passing to smtplib.sendmail()

Comment: Thanks I should have looked at it more carefully.